# Run time error 1004 in loop for multiplication of column

Tags: vba, excel

I have designed a code to multiply two columns with the use of an if else statement but I am getting an `error 1004` on   `L = Cells(i, "L").Value` Hence I need some clarification to why this is happening. 
This is the code!

```
Sub IfCalculationEq1()

    Dim lastrow As Long

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim i As Long
    Dim L As Long
    Dim E As Long


    lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, "L").End(xlUp).Row

    L = Cells(i, "L").Value
    E = Cells(i, "E").Value

    For i = 3 To lastrow

    If Cells(i, "K").Value = "-" Then

    Cells(i, "N").Value = "-"

    Else

     Cells(i, "N").Formula = "=L*E"

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

   ' If k is null then no action required or else L1*E3

   End If

   Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`i` is unititialized at the line `L = Cells(i, "L").Value`, so it has a value of 0.  The cells array is 1 based.

Comment: Got it thanks! I ran it and i realised it does not work probably because excel does not recognize the L*E function. How do i go about that?

Comment: @Niva - Not exactly sure what the formula you're trying to build is, but I'm guessing it should be something like `Cells(i, "N").Formula = "=L" & i & " * E" & i`